# A question regarding Differential Equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

$f'(x) = 1+f(x) \implies \frac{df(x)}{1+f(x)} = dx$

Now on integrating both sides we get $f(x) = e^{x+c} -1$

So $f(x) = e^{x+c}  -1$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$

This is done in my text book.

But I can not understand why they did not care about $1+f(x) $ being $0$.

I would rather prefer to do the following.

Let's supose $1+f(x) \neq 0$ when $x\in A$. So we can say $f(x) = e^{x+c}  -1$ when $x \in A$  by using the previous method.

And $f(x) = -1$ when $x \in \mathbb R -A$

Now as $\mathbb R$ is a connected set and $f(x)$ is continuous , we can say either $A= \mathbb R$ or $B= \mathbb R$.

Can anyone please tell me if I have gone wrong anywhere?

Comment: Your first implication is wrong. It should be either $\frac{f'(x)}{1+f(x)}=1$ or $\frac{\,\mathrm d f}{f+1}=\,\mathrm d x$

Comment: how can one ignore such a big thing ? @Surb

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3938082/showing-a-solution-to-this-differential-equation-is-never-zero

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that you have to assume $1+f(x) \neq 0$ in order to carry out this procedure of separation of variables. You didn't do the rest of it right, though. You actually have

$$\ln(|f(x)+1|)=x+C \\
|f(x)+1|=e^C e^x \\
f(x)=-1 \pm e^C e^x.$$

You can simplify this by identifying $\pm e^C$ as a new constant $C$ that can be any nonzero value, and then writing $f(x)=-1+Ce^x$.

Still, separation of variables can't see that $f(x)=-1$ is a solution; it forces the constant to be nonzero as part of the method.

However, you can readily see that $f(x)=-1$ is a solution, since it will have $f'(x)=0$. So to finish the problem, you can argue that the solutions to IVPs in this equation are unique (using Picard-Lindelof or some variant thereof). So you conclude that if $f(x)=-1$ anywhere then $f(x)=-1$ everywhere. From there you finish the problem with $f(x)=-1+Ce^x$ for any real constant $C$.

This isn't the only way to do it. Since this equation is first order linear you can follow the integrating factor method, or use the "particular + homogeneous" technique that works with linear equations in general. These methods don't have this case work like separation of variables does.

Answer (score 3):

$$f'(x) = 1+f(x) $$
$$f'(x)-f(x)=1$$
Multiply by the integrating factor $\mu=e^{-x}$:
$$(f(x)e^{-x})'=e^{-x}$$
$$f(x)e^{-x}=-e^{-x}+C$$
$$\implies f(x)=Ce^x-1$$
The solution $f(x)=-1$ corresponds to $C=0$.

Comment: Can I use this method for homogeneous Linear First order differential Equation @MtGlasser

Comment: @sani  Yes  you can use this method too