# Solving the differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt} = -x$ with initial condition $x(0) = -1$.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, initial-value-problems

I've gotten all the way down to

$$\ln x =-t+c.$$

Then, $x = \exp(-t+c) = \exp(c)\cdot\exp(-t)$.

I've seen a few places where this has been given as the right final answer but I've also seen $x=c\cdot\exp(-t)$ and I don't understand that last step.

In case I can use $c\cdot\exp (-t)$ and $\exp(c)\cdot\exp (-t)$ interchangeably and then plug in my initial values. I get $c = -1$ for the $c\cdot\exp(-t)$ variant but I'm not sure how I would solve it for the other. $-1 = \exp (-0+c) \implies -1 = \exp (c)$ as far as I know there is no real solution for that.

Could someone explain very easily and clearly, I haven't done math in several years.

All help appreciated.

Comment: Hello, please use mathjax to type mathematics (i.e. write $\$\dots\$$).

Comment: Because it's $\ln |x|$ instead of $\ln x$.

Comment: When you have a choice (like in this case), it's usually much easier to use an integrating factor rather than the method of separation of variables. Then problems of this type never arise. For example, see this question for a similar situation: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4205538/a-question-regarding-differential-equation

Comment: @HansLundmark Thank you this was very useful. I haven't learned integrating factors yet only separation of variables. Do you recommend any good sources?

Comment: **Every** source in the world that says anything about differential equations will explain integrating factors! (OK, I'm maybe exaggerating a little, but not much.)

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out in the comments, the first issue is that when you solve
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = -x$$ you should get $\ln|x| = -t+c$ instead of simply $\ln(x) = -t+c$.  In this case, upon exponentiation, you obtain $$|x| = \exp(-t+c) = \exp(c)\exp(-t).$$  Now, since $\exp(c)$ is itself a constant, you could express this as $|x| = C\exp(-t)$.  It's important to note that $C$ and $\exp(c)$ are not necessarily equal, but considering $c$ as an arbitrary constant you would still be justified in expressing the solution as $c\exp(-t)$.  In this case, you proceed as you did and obtain $x(t) = -\exp(-t)$.  If, however, you want to use the form $|x| = \exp(c)\exp(-t)$ then you have to observe that this implies that $$x(t) = \pm\exp(c)\exp(-t).$$  To choose the correct sign you observe that $$-1 = x(0) = \pm\exp(c) \implies -1 = \color{red}-\exp(c) \implies c = 0.$$  Again you arrive at $$x(t) = -\exp(-t).$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-x$$
$$\int\frac1x\frac{dx}{dt}dt=-\int dt$$
$$\ln|x|=-t+C$$
$$|x|=C_1\exp(-t)$$
$$x=\pm C_1\exp(-t)$$
now notice that:
$$\exp(-t)>0\quad\forall t\in\mathbb R$$
and so we must have $\pm C_1\ge0$

Answer (score 0):

Differently from the other approaches, let us solve it through the integrating factor method:
\begin{align*}
x' = -x & \Longleftrightarrow x' + x = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \exp(t)x' + \exp(t)x = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow [\exp(t)x]' = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \exp(t)x = c\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x(t) = c\exp(-t)
\end{align*}

Since $x(0) = -1$, we obtain the desired solution $x(t) = -\exp(-t)$, where $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Hopefully this helps!